# Mpdf errơr during PHP output?

Tags: php, wordpress, mpdf

I have an error and don't know why. When I delete part of the form with checkbox it works. When I add it back has this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /footer.php:22) in mpdf/mpdf.php on line 9420 Fatal
>   error: Uncaught MpdfException: Some data has already been output to
>   browser, can't send PDF file in mpdf/mpdf.php:9422 Stack trace: #0
>   page-kontakt.php(421): mPDF->Output('Zamowienie2.pdf', 'D')

```
<?php
get_footer();
require("mpdf/mpdf.php");
require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $mpdf = new Mpdf('utf-8', 'A4');
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth');

    $custom_company_data = $_POST['nazwa'];
    $custom_street = $_POST['ulica'];
    $custom_post_code = $_POST['kod'];
    $custom_city = $_POST['miejscowosc'];
    $custom_nip = $_POST['nip'];
    $custom_type = $_POST['typ'];
    $custom_place = $_POST['miejsce'];
    $custom_date = $_POST['data'];
    $custom_time = $_POST['czas'];
    $custom_work_time = $_POST['worktime'];
    $custom_phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $custom_description = $_POST['opis'];
    $custom_work = $_POST['praca'];
    $custom_dojazd = $_POST['dojazd'];
    $custom_ryczalt = $_POST['ryczalt'];
    $custom_cash = $_POST['gotowka'];
    $custom_bank_wire = $_POST['przelew'];
    $custom_ile_dni=$_POST['ile_dni'];
    $custom_vat = $_POST['vat'];
    $custom_odwrotne = $_POST['odwrotne'];
    $custom_by_post = $_POST['poczta'];
    $custom_send_an_email = $_POST['elektroniczne'];
    $custom_address = $_POST['naadres'];
    $custom_pdf_name = date("Y-m-d") . '-' . $custom_company_data;
    $custom_vat = $_POST['vat'];
    $custom_odwrotne = $_POST['odwrotne'];

    if(($_POST['platnosc1'])=='Gotówka'){
        $platnosc='Gotówka';
    }
    elseif(($_POST['platnosc2'])=='Przelew w terminie'){
        $platnosc='Przelewem w terminie: '.$custom_ile_dni;
    }
    else{
        $platnosc='Nie Wybrano opcji';
    }
    echo $custom_company_data . '</br>';

    if(($_POST['vat1']=='VAT23%')){
        $vat='23%';
    }
    elseif(($_POST['vat2']=='Odwrotne obciazenie')){
        $vat='Odwrotne obciążenie';
    }
    else{
        echo'Nie podano formy VATU';
    }
    if(($_POST['wysylka1']=='poczta')){
        $wysylka='Poczta';
    }
    elseif(($_POST['wysylka2']=='elektronicznie')){
        $wysylka='Elektronicznie na e-mail: ' .$custom_address;
    }
    else{
        echo'Nie podano formy wysyłki faktury';
    }

    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('some html footer...');

    $html='some html content...';

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output("./wp-content/themes/xxxx/pdf/Zamowienie-$custom_pdf_name.pdf", 'F');
    $mpdf->Output('Zamowienie2.pdf', 'D');
}
?>
```

Comment: Still the same problems with output when I add some html but now in
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at page-kontakt.php:10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`footer.php` (probably included by `get_footer();`) outputs something in line 22, which results in (implicit) response headers being set. This results in `$mpdf->Output('Zamowienie2.pdf', 'D');` not being able to set the (same!) response's headers anymore... I guess it tries to set the MIME type `application/pdf`, while the footer already set MIME type `text/html` (or similar).

Try to comment `get_footer()` out and see if this fixes it. Or if it at least changes the error.

Comment: Great it working. I just moved get_footer on the bottom. Thank you.
Do you know how to change font-size in mpdf? I try to add inline and mpdf.css, and it doesn't work.